# Old cartoon about some characters looking for elemental crystals

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I remember as a kid watching a movie where there's a guy who is topless, and he searches for some magical elemental crystals. He has a crystal that when he puts in a hole in a cave during sunset it reveals a map, and one crystal is hidden behind a waterfall. Later that guy is imprisoned inside a volcano and his life force is drained, so his girlfriend does something and he wakes up and they sing this song that goes like "It's about love ....", then a villain used the power of the crystals to control Mother Nature and the island is destroyed.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question, where you can find some tips on things to [edit] into your question to improve your chance of getting an answer. If someone does post the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark as per the [tour].

Comment: When did you see it?